# Mule: how to log SOAP payloads when using WS Consumer component

Tags: mule, mule-component

I'm using WS Consumer component to call an external WS from a Mule flow. 
I would like to log the SOAP payloads of the request and response sent/received by the WS Consumer. 
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been addressed for the HTTP transport under the ticket MULE-7501:
https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-7501

So, the following line needs to be added to the log4j2.xml:

```
<AsyncLogger name="org.mule.module.http.internal.HttpMessageLogger" level="DEBUG"/>
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work when WS Consumer is using transports other than HTTP (like JMS for example).

Update:

The more correct way of logging the SOAP payloads with WS Consume is  configuring CXF interceptors as per the following description:
http://cxf.apache.org/docs/configuration.html

This way it works with non http transports.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this log handler in log4j2.xml or log4j.xml,

```
    <AsyncLogger name="org.glassfish.grizzly" level="INFO" />
    <AsyncLogger name="org.asynchttpclient" level="INFO" />
    <AsyncLogger name="sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.level" level="ALL" />
    <AsyncLogger name="org.apache.http.wire" level="ALL" />
    <AsyncLogger name="org.apache.http.client" level="ALL" />
    <AsyncLogger name="org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser" level="ALL" />
    <AsyncLogger name="com.ning.http" level="ALL" />
```